# Why paxos acceptor must send back any value they have already accepted

Tags: distributed, paxos

I'm learning MIT 6.824 class and I have a question about paxos. When proposer send a prepare to acceptor, acceptor will return a prepare_ok with n and v which highest accept see. I wonder why acceptor need to return n and v?

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell, the acceptor must return v because if the value was already committed then the new proposer needs to know what it is. There is no global "is_committed" flag, so the proposer gathers all these values and their associated rounds from at least a majority of the acceptors. The proposer then sends the value with the highest round to all the acceptors.

As you can see, a proposer always finishes what another proposer has started when it receives a value from an acceptor. This is a little bit similar to a lot of wait-free algorithms.

Comment: To add to what Michael says the key point about why they return both `n` and `v` is that under complex network outages many nodes could have issued different `accept(n,v)` messages with different values of `n` and `v` in each. So the new leader may see multiple `prepareAck(n,v)` and it sorts them by `n` and picks the highest message then uses that value in it's `accept(n',v)` message. The "magic" of Paxos is that the new leader waits to see a majority response then it is guaranteed that all possible leaders would choose the same `v`.

Comment: Another fact is that potentially the node which steps up to lead may not have seen the original `accept(n,v)` that is the chosen value. So you can optimise the algorithm to send a hash of `v` if the values are large so that if it has seen that `v` you don't need to retransmit it over the network but you have to account for the fact that the new leader may never have encountered that value so it must be transmitted to it so that the leader may broadcast it out as its chosen value.